# How to find the Prime numbers below user input in LabVIEW using case structure?

Tags: primes, labview

I am doing LabVIEW for the first time. I am a complete newbie. Actually with the help of YouTube and National Instruments documentation, I did a script to find out prime numbers below a certain user input and I am attaching it hereby. After that, I tried to modify it by bringing case structure into the loop, but unfortunately I could not come up with the desired output. I would really appreciate any help to complete the script with case structure.
Thank you.

1. Using `for` looping a for loop, I found the desired output and its stored in an array.
2. I obtained the desired output from the remainder-quotient function. (Refer Image for clarification)

Desired output: Find out the prime numbers below the given user input using case structure

[image]

Comment: Oops. Looks like you forgot to post your code. Please don't be tempted to post images/hyperlinks

Comment: @Fred Excuse me and Thank you for clarifying.The image is shared now.

Comment: What does this have to do with MATLAB, Python or vi? Please attach only meaningful tags, otherwise you’re just annoying the people that might be able to help you.

Comment: Please dont hesitate to post if someone has a solution for it..Thank you

Comment: could you edit your post to include explanation for each node in the diagram?

Comment: @WillNess why do you need that? If someone can't understand that simple code, he will not be able to provide the answer anyway. Code is very simple, no need to include explanation for each node.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to use case structures to bypass 0 and 1 in the divisor test (and potentially bypass them too in the list of numbers to test).

In your block diagram, you need to manually add 2 to offset the divisor but, as you don't substract 2 from your loop limit, you will divide the number by itself plus 1 at the end.

I think you can improve your code by using case structures to bypass 0 and 1 in both the dividend and the divisor cases.

Here is a VI snippet, you can drag and drop it in a block diagram.

[image: VI snippet]